# Power BI: Columna calculada promedio últimos X valores

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una tabla de datos importada en Power BI con 2 columnas: Día y Gastos. Me gustaría que tuviese la siguiente estructura con una nueva columna llamada 'Promedio última semana', en la que se calcularía el promedio de gastos de los últimos 7 días. El resultado sería algo así:

```
Día      Gastos      Promedio última semana
1          10                10
2          20                15
3          10                13.3
4           5                11.2
5          10                11
6          40                15.8 
7           5                14.2 
8          10                15.7  
9          12                17.7
```

¿Qué formula o función debería aplicar en esta nueva columna para que solo tuviese en cuenta los datos de los últimos 7 días? Por ejemplo, en el día 8 se omitiría la información del día 1, en la del día 9 se omitirían los gastos del día 1 y 2 y así sucesivamente. Gracias de antemano y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente formula se puede:

```
Moving Average = 
CALCULATE (AVERAGE (Tabla[Gastos]), Tabla[Día] <= MAX (Tabla[Día]) && Tabla[Día]> MAX (Tabla[Día]) - 7)
```

Con lo anterior, obtienes lo siguiente para tu ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me funciona con este código, no sé que esté haciendo mal, pero me aparece esto: Es una tabla exportada de excel con dos columnas de día y gastos [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaSjn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaSjn.png)